# Tomcat logging to multiple files

Tags: logging, tomcat7

I am using tomcat in ubuntu to write logs for my application. I see that in folder

/var/log/tomcat7/

i have multiple log files. e.g. catalina.out, catalina.out.1.gz, catalina.out.2.gz and so on.

**1) What is the difference in catalina.out and catalina.out.x.gz files?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GZ file means compressed files created using the gzip compression utility.

catalina.out is your main file in tomcat and probably catalina.out.1.gz and 2.gz are the backed up files when catalina.out file size is filled.

Comment: Where can i find the settings to see the maximum file file before a new file is created?